# javascript "don't make function in a loop"

Tags: javascript

How can I refractor my code to get rid of this error from JSLinter?
I tried moving the entire function out to a var but the code wasn't able to run after that.

```
  for (i = 0; i < timeDifference; i++) {
    timestamp ++;
    console.log(timestamp);
    energyDatum.find({timestamp: timestamp}).toArray(function(err, result) {
      var data = {};
      result.forEach(function(element) {
        data[element.deviceId] = element;
      });

      var roomRawData = [];
      mappings.forEach(function(room) {
        var hash = {};
        hash.floor = room.floor;
        hash.name = room.name;
        hash.room_type = room.room_type;
        hash.energy_ac = sumApplianceEnergy('energy_ac', room, data);
        hash.energy_light = sumApplianceEnergy('energy_light', room, data);
        hash.energy_socket_1 = sumApplianceEnergy('energy_socket_1', room, data);
        hash.energy_socket_2 = sumApplianceEnergy('energy_socket_2', room, data);
        hash.energy_socket_3 = sumApplianceEnergy('energy_socket_3', room, data);
        hash.energy_total = hash.energy_ac + hash.energy_light + hash.energy_socket_1 + hash.energy_socket_2 + hash.energy_socket_3;
        hash.timestamp = timestamp;
        roomRawData.push(hash);
      });

      roomRaw.insert(roomRawData, {w:1}, function(err, result) { console.log('done'); });

    });

    lastTimestamp.update({_id: timestampId}, {timestamp: timestamp});
  }
```

Comment: "the code wasn't able to run after that" isn't meaningful. Did you get any errors in the console? If you did, what were they?

Comment: You're closing over `roomRawData` in the inner function. You could get it out of the loop, but you'd have to pass `roomRawData` as an argument, rather than as a closure. I've never worked with JSLinter, so I'm not sure which functions are bothering it the most, though.

Comment: I think it doesn't like the function expression for the `toArray` callback. Just disable this rule, there's nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSLinter shows this message because your code has potential errors.

Take a look at this line:

```
energyDatum.find({timestamp: timestamp}).toArray(...);
```

This method is async, right? It means that the callback of `toArray` method
is called ***after*** the `for` loop finishes its iterations, and therefore `timestamp`
variable (when you use it inside this callback) doesn't have a value of current iteration,
but instead it has value incremented for `timeDifference` times.

To solve this problem you could move this callback to another function:

```
var getIterationFunc = function(timestamp) {
    return function(err, result) {
        var data = {};
        // rest of function ...         
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
energyDatum.find({timestamp: timestamp}).toArray(getIterationFunc(timestamp));
```

I believe this error should be fixed now. Hope this helps.

P.S. sorry for my English